# How to receive TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER AccessibilityEvent?

Tags: android, hover, accessibility

I override my own Accessibility Service, and print the event.getEventType to Log in

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(Accessibility event)
```

TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED and TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED can be seen, but there is no TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_ENTER and TYPE_VIEW_HOVER_EXIT.

I also set CAPABILITY_CAN_REQUEST_TOUCH_EXPLORATION in AccessibilityServiceInfo.

How to receive Hover AccessibilityEvents?
What's the relationship between Exploration by Touch and Accessibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should set the flags as `FLAG_REQUEST_TOUCH_EXPLRORATION_MODE`

Comment: And declare `android:canRequestTouchExplorationMode="true"` in the configuration XML (if above Jellybean MR1).